# "Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key"- when submitting an edit/update form

Tags: django

I have an edit form that I only want to update the "title", "content", and "category" of a Post. To this end, I have included `update_fields` when saving the form. However, there's a wee issue with this. Django raises a ValueError (specifically "Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key") when I submit the form. Why is it doing this, and how can I fix this?

Post form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key in ['postTitle', 'postContent', 'category']:
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})         
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs.update(width='100px', height='50')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'category')
```

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    URL = models.SlugField() # slug for url 
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'posts') # id of author
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 9, default = 'General') # category the post is in
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField()
```

Edit view:

```
def editPost(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = pk)
        if post.author == request.user:
            form = PostForm(instance = post)
            return render(request, 'editPost.html',  {'form': form, 'post': post})
        else:
            return redirect('viewPost', pk = pk, postURL = post.postURL)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = pk)
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if post.author == request.user:
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.URL = slugify(post.postTitle)
                post.save(update_fields = ['title', 'content', 'category', 'postURL'])
    return redirect('viewAll')
```

Comment: I haven't used forms before, but can you confirm which line causes the exception here? Could it be raised on post = form.save(commit=False) line?

Comment: it's raised on the last form.save() line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are re-assigning post here. In this line;

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = pk)
```

You are getting a Post instance from the database. Then in this line;

```
post = form.save(commit=False)
```

You are re-assigning post variable to an unsaved instance of a Post, populated with only the data that is available in request.POST. Then, when you want to save this post with an **update_fields** argument like this:

```
post.save(update_fields = ['title', 'content', 'category', 'postURL'])
```

ValueError is raised because the Post instance you are trying to save does not have an id, it only has what is available in **request.POST**

Comment: This was my suspicion.

Comment: Ok- I changed it from `form = PostForm(request.POST)` to form = PostForm(request.POST, instance = post)`. Now for another silly question, since I'm pretty awful at security- would changing this line open any security holes that I may not be aware of?

Comment: @vjwvebjkwev I am not sure, haven't worked with forms before, but how would the code behave if I were to send a post request to /posts/5 (lets say I am the author of the post with id 5), but provide another id in the request POST data? Could I change the author field of another post as my user? In general, this does not look like the best practice to update a model instance with django forms.

Comment: Good catch! (this is why I say I am not the best when it comes to security...:p) I added a line of code that checks the instance of the form (with request.POST) with the current user as well as checks the main post variable.