# Why is Primary Key not being created for new form in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, forms

After I submit my form the body does not include a primary key. So when I try to save in form_valid() I receive an error: `Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.` See `views.py` below; it breaks on that final `.save()`.

The answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121088/cannot-force-an-update-in-save-with-no-primary-key-when-submitting-an-edit) was very helpful in framing the problem: my first form.save(commit=False) populates the data from the POST from the form. And when I `print (self.request.body)` I see the other values like gallons and customer. But I don't see index (which is the primary key).

I could just create a primary key in `views.py` like so:

```
self.object.index = WorkOrderTable.objects.all().order_by('index').first().index +1
```

Note the +1; I'm just finding the last record/work_order and adding one to that pk. But I get the feeling since 'index' is an Autofield it should already be doing this. And I may regret my work-around down the road.

forms.py

```
class WorkOrderForm(ModelForm):
    customer = ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.CustomersTable.objects.order_by('firstname','lastname'))
    class Meta:
        model = models.WorkOrderTable
        exclude = []
```

models.py

```
class WorkOrderTable(BasicModelFields):
    index = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('CustomersTable', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='wo_customers')
    median_gallons = computed_property.ComputedIntegerField(compute_from='_get_median_gallons')


    def _get_median_gallons(self):
        "Returns the work orders' customer's median gallons pumped."
        median_gallons = customer_median_gallons(self.customer)
        return median_gallons

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return utils.detail_reverse(self)

    def __str__(self):
        label = '{}'.format(self.customer)
        return '{}'.format(label)
```

views.py

```
class DynamicCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.kwargs['model_name'] == 'WorkOrderTable':
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            g = geocoder.google(self.object.customer.address, key = APIKey)
            lat,lon = g.latlng
            self.object.longitude = lon
            self.object.latitude = lat
        else:
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()   #It breaks on this save()  
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

EDIT:
When I change the final save from `self.object.save()` to `self.object.save(force_insert = True)` it works without having to manually create a pk. I don't know if I would count this as the answer since it seems like a work around and I don't know why it works. Just providing that info in case that clues someone in who can explain why that works and/or knows a better way.

EDIT:
Just showing what the inherited model class is. So also in `models.py`:

```
class BasicModelFields(models.Model):
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField('Last Updated', auto_now=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now_add=True)   
    # updated_date.editable=True

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Please show the code for `BasicModelFields`.